# Do levels from Mnemonic Enhancer stack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Will the ability to prepare "three additional levels of spells" provided by [Mnemonic Enhancer](http://paizo.com/prd/spells/mnemonicEnhancer.html) stack?

Ie if Mighty Wizard Bob casts this twice at midnight does that mean he has:

1. Three levels of spells extra to prepare (no stacking at all)
2. Six levels of spell to prepare (maximum spell level 3)
3. Six levels of spell to prepare (no maximum to spell level)
4. Something else

[Related Question - does mnemonic enhancer give you extra spells the next day?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/21497/does-mnemonic-enhancer-give-you-extra-spells-the-next-day)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### It is impossible to be affected by multiple *mnemonic enhancers* at once

*Mnemonic enhancer* has a duration of Instantaneous. You cannot be under the effect of more than one at a time. If you cast it twice in a row, you get its effect once (preparing three levels’ worth of spells or retaining one spell of up to third level just cast) instantaneously, and **then** you cast it again and get to repeat the process.

Laying everything out, you follow these steps:

1. You cast *mnemonic enhancer*
2. You prepare up to three spell levels’ worth of spells, or retain a spell of up to third level
3. *Mnemonic enhancer* ends
4. You cast *mnemonic enhancer* again
5. Repeat steps 2. and 3.

In other words, “stacking” per se never comes up, because the two effects are completely independent from one another.

Comment: I see the text "You prepare and cast these spells normally." in the spell. What is the significance of the normal prep for these extra spells? Just an additional environment constraints and the 15 minutes it takes to prep some spells?

Comment: @ColinD I read it as you preparing those spells during the spell itself (i.e. instantaneously, after you’ve spent 10 minutes casting it), following all the normal rules of preparation (aside from the time it takes). If it merely freed up some spell slots in which you could then prepare spells, I think it would simply *say that*. But even if we read it that way, those spell slots would have to be chosen before the spell ended (since there’s no such thing as preparing *X* levels of spells, just preparing *Y* spells of various levels), and thus you still could not combine the levels from two.

Comment: From your 1. to 5. steps it seems like this would give option 2. from my list of possibilities; I.e. Wizard Bob would gain 3 levels of spell he can prepare from the first cast of ME and then another 3 from the second.

Answer (score 4):

Option 2: Six levels of spell to prepare (maximum spell level 3)

stacking rules only applies to 'bonuses' which have an overloaded meaning that limits it so it does not apply to all positive effects.

http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/glossary#TOC-Bonus

> **Bonuses are numerical values that are added to checks and statistical
>   scores**. Most bonuses have a type, and as a general rule, bonuses of
>   the same type are not cumulative (do not “stack”)—only the greater
>   bonus granted applies.

As for picking between option 2 or 3, I do not have a rules citation. However, since the spells are cast separately, I could only imagine that the effects are separate and you would get to prepare up up to 3 levels of spells twice. Further, I would not allow a player to turn 2 level 4 spells into 1 level 6 spell or 3 level 4 spells into a level 9 spell. That just seems way to powerful.

Comment: 2 seems most likely. You prepare the three levels of spell as soon as you cast Mnemonic Enhancer. When you cast the second one, those three levels of spell are already prepared and not available.